# PagedList doesn't work on IE but works on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I am working in ASP.NET MVC 4.0 with VS2012, my application is displayed properly in Chrome and Firefox but not properly displayed in IE8 and above version. I am using mvc PagedList control and [noty alert message plugin](http://ned.im/noty/) in application both are properly displayed in Chrome and Firefox but not displayed properly IE versions.

Here is my code:

```
<table border="0">
      <tr>
         <td>Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount</td>
         <td>
              @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }).Normalize(), PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast)
         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: It may be because of css rules of javascript code, thats not readable by ie

Comment: can you please explain what doesn't work properly?

Comment: Hit F12. Is your page in Compatibility View because you're viewing it from an Intranet URL?

Comment: I have tried it but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the top of your view. This might work!

Comment: Thanks pavitar my problem get resolved after adding this line above <html> tag